# Validacion fecha mvc data annotations

Tags: c#, mvc, validación

tengo una pregunta. 
Tengo una vista de generar movimientos de articulos pero me gustaria validar que la fecha de salida del producto no sea antes de la fecha de entrada? alguna validacion que me recomienden, de momento tengo estas.. Ademas me gustaria validar de que la fecha de entrada no sea antes del dia actual en el que estamos (por ejemplo hoy es 3/31/2020 entonces que no me deje registrar una entrada ayer 3/30/2020)

Codigo:

```
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> FechaAdquisicion { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]

    public Nullable<System.DateTime> FechaSalida { get; set; }
```

Comment: Lectura obligatoria mi estimado: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Answer (score 1):

Puedes implementar `IValidatableObject` en tu modelo:

```
public class ClaseViewModel: IValidatableObject
{

[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> FechaAdquisicion { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]

public Nullable<System.DateTime> FechaSalida { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
       if (FechaSalida < FechaAdquisicion)
       {
           yield return 
             new ValidationResult(errorMessage: "EndDate must be greater than StartDate",
                                  memberNames: new[] { "EndDate" });
       }
    }
}
```